Can't install/find modules via Python code (while compiled)
I have a Python script that when ran in the ide and/or as a .py file in general, it works just fine. All the modules are found and imported properly. Then the issue arose, for some reason when I compile the script via auto-py-to-exe the finding and importing of the modules just goes completely out of wack. The executable can't find any of the modules, so in return tries to install them all again. On top of that the program seems to be having issues just installing them in general but I'm more-so worried about the fact that it can't even find said modules.
Just extra info:

I want to keep the progress bar and stuff if that's even applicable.
The actual packages are not in the script so everything's not as long ([packages]).

At the current code stated below, I get this outcome which is just a loop of it asking to install the req modules so it's a little broken right now. Here is what I'm seeing:

-> Uninstalled Modules Found, Install Them? (y/n)
y


2024-05-27 15:22:01,074 - DEBUG - Installing missing modules...


2024-05-27 15:22:01,315 - DEBUG - Checking for missing modules...


2024-05-27 15:22:01,390 - INFO - Missing packages: [packages]


Uninstalled Modules Found, Install Them? (y/n)
y


2024-05-27 15:22:05,059 - DEBUG - Installing missing modules...


2024-05-27 15:22:05,301 - DEBUG - Checking for missing modules...


2024-05-27 15:22:05,372 - INFO - Missing packages: [packages]


Uninstalled Modules Found, Install Them? (y/n)
y

and then the loop repeats from there.
This is the code I'm using to get there:
imports (shortened, req imports are here)


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


def install_package(package):
    """Install a single package using pip."""
    try:
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
        logging.info(f"Successfully installed {package}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred while installing {package}: {e}")

def install_packages_with_progress(packages):
    """Install multiple packages with a progress bar."""
    for package in tqdm(packages, desc="Installing Packages", ncols=100):
        install_package(package)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def check_missing_packages(packages):
    """Check for missing packages and return a list of them."""
    missing_packages = []
    for package in packages:
        try:
            pkg_resources.require(package)
        except (pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound, pkg_resources.VersionConflict):
            missing_packages.append(package)
    return missing_packages

def clear_screen():
    """Clear the terminal screen."""
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system("cls")
    else:
        os.system("clear")
    print("\033[H\033[J", end="")

clear_screen()

required_packages = [
    packages
]

logging.debug("Checking for missing modules...")
missing_packages = check_missing_packages(required_packages)

if missing_packages:
    logging.info(f"Missing packages: {missing_packages}")
    install = input(" -> Uninstalled Modules Found, Install Them? (y/n)\n>> ").strip().lower() == "y"

    if install:
        logging.debug("Installing missing modules...")
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

        install_packages_with_progress(missing_packages)

        # Re-check for missing packages after installation
        missing_packages = check_missing_packages(required_packages)
        
        if not missing_packages:
            logging.debug("All required modules installed successfully! Reboot the program...")
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            logging.error("Some modules could not be installed. Please check the errors and try again.")
            exit(1)
    else:
        logging.debug("Aborting installation...")
        exit(1)
else:
    logging.debug("All required modules are already installed.")

clear_screen()
exit()

This is only like this when the script is compiled, when it's ran in the IDE or as a normal py file it works perfectly fine and finds all the modules correctly.

python wasn't invented to create .exe files (or rather self extracing .zip file with extension .exe) and programs like auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller sometimes may have problem to find all needed Python modules, and C/C++ libraries. In pyinstaller you could use special file .spec to manually add all needed files - modules, libraries, images, files with data, etc.
